# SQL Server 2012 - date not sort as expected

Tags: sql-server, sorting

Alright, I searched each and every option upon SQL related to sorting a date column. Most of them say that it's not correctly sort because the column is of type `nvarchar`. This is not my case.

My table and query:

[image: my actual database table as well as the query I used].

Injection aside, as you can see in the image, I want the column that I selected in the image to be in correct order - the 7th column (I am sorry for the native column name); however, it is not. To be more precise, that 1660 row is not sorted correctly, while all other rows stay in the line.

I tried ascending order, and as you may guess it, it's that 1660 row that stays in the last regardless of other row's value.

I also tried sorting by other columns with similar type - 6th, 8th and 9th, and they're working fine.

The 1660 row doesn't have any special column, nor its date is any special. It just between lots of other rows, between June and July.

These time columns are inserted using vb.net through a DatetimePicker value.

So can someone shed me some light into this case, as to why, how, or what is the cause of this disorder... It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 1660 row has a date in the year 2106, not the year 2016. This is obvious from looking at the image. It is not a formatting error or a sorting error; it is a typo in your actual data.

Comment: wow, thank you for pointing that out. I must be blind, as I expected my user to just insert the right thing. I guess i'll have to make a check before letting the data go into the database.

Yes, thanks again, I deserve a -1 for this.